# Why do my AMQP messages spool up before sending

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I have an problem where publishing around twenty AMQP messages to a shared queue in RabbitMQ get delayed in batch before another consumer receives the messages. My application topology has three endpoints:

1. The first endpoint will generate a batch of messages with each one containing the FQDN of a network device to collect a configuration file from. There will be one instance of this endpoint and is the lone publisher to a direct queue called net.svc.ssh.
2. The second endpoint will consume one of those messages, SSH into a specified network device, run a CLI command and publish the result from each device to another queue. There will be multiple instances of this endpoint all of which consume from net.svc.ssh and publish to net.svc.savefile.
3. The third endpoint will receive that result and save it to local disk in its own separate file. This instance is the lone consumer of net.svc.savefile and publishes no messages.

What I see is that all of the second endpoints will "hold on" to their outgoing messages until there are no messages left to consume from the ssh queue. This prevents the timely delivering of device configurations to the final endpoint. What I am observing is that every configuration is coming in at the same time once all the middle endpoints have consumed their messages.

So my question is why do I see this spooling behavior? I would like my messages to be published the moment they are ready and this behavior is not intended.

endpoint 1 - sender of network device backup requests:

```
EventMachine.add_timer( 0 ) do
  YAML::load_file( 'hosts.yaml' ).each do |fqdn,ip|
    payload = { :fqdn => fqdn }
    exchange.publish( payload.to_json, :routing_key => 'net.svc.ssh' )
  end
end
```

endpoint 2 - ssh node

```
mq_queue.subscribe( :ack => false ) do |meta, mq_payload|
  payload = JSON.parse( mq_payload)

  # SSH stuff happens here

  mq_channel.default_exchange.publish( payload.to_json,
                                       :routing_key => 'net.svc.savefile',
                                       )
  end
end
```

endpoint 3 - node that saves device configuration to file

```
queue.subscribe( ) do |meta, mq_payload|
  payload = JSON.parse( mq_payload )
  payload[ "host" ].each do |host,hash|
    File.open( File.join('backups', host), "w" ) do |file|
      result = hash[ "result" ]
      if( result[ "error" ].nil? )
        file << result[ "show running-config" ].join( "\n" )
      else
        file << result[ "error" ]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you are publishing messages to a topic exchange with default behaviour. I assume that your consumers (are there multiple instances) are subscribed to a queue with a simple binding on the routing key, i.e. multiple consumers will take messages round robin.

Or maybe there is only one consumer.

I haven't used Ruby for years so I'm not familiar with the quirks of various libraries, but I can't see where your consumers ACK the messages after dealing with them. On consumer 2 you seem to have explicitly set auto-ack to FALSE which is good, and in consumer 3 you have not set it so perhaps that means auto-ack is happening.

When I write a consumer that publishes results on another queue, I do things in this order:

1. get the incoming message
2. do the work
3. publish new message to the result queue
4. ack the incoming message